# Overwriting get_by_key_name() to use memcache

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Does it make sense to overwrite get_by_key_name with another function that uses memcache to save on database queries? Like below? In this example the memcache key consists of only the entity key_name just to make it simple...

```
class Entity(db.Model):
   @classmethod
   def get_by_key_name(cls, key_name):
     entity = memcache.get(key_name)
     if entity is not None:
       return entity
     else:
       entity = cls.__super__.get_by_key_name(key_name)
       memcache.add(key_name, entity, 3600)
       return entity
```

Comment: `cls.__super__.get_by_key_name` is correctly spelled `super(Entity, cls).get_by_key_name`.

Comment: Good comments guys, went though this quickly.

Comment: If nothing else, you also need to clear the cache whenever you update or remove an existing entity: "There are only two hard problems in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things." -- Phil Karlton (if I believe the internet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better and neater solution would be to use [NDB](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/), which has built in support for memcache and instance memory caching.

Answer (score 2):

Whether it makes sense depends on:

1. Whether the performance of your application is not good enough (what is your performance goal and how are you measuring it?)
2. Whether the database query is really a bottleneck for your application (the performance issue may actually lie elsewhere, which you won't know until you profile)
3. Whether the memcache query is actually faster than the database's cache (if any) and by how much (repeated queries of the same record(s) from your database is likely going to come from RAM anyway)
4. Your application's query pattern (you're actually doing more work per query if the record's not already in the memcache, so if most of your queries are unique, it could even be slower! -- the database's cache may also be sufficient)

It is possible someone has already measured some of this for Google App Engine, but #4 is still going to be something you need to figure out for your application. In other words: not really a question that can be answered without more data. However, hopefully I've given you some places to start investigating.

Depending on how well you know databases and SQL, it's also possible that you could speed up the queries just by using the database better, without adding the complication of caching to your application (don't really know enough about GAE to know how much of this it lets you do).

As for your proposed implementation, it doesn't look unreasonable, since `get_by_key_name()` is already a class method. You *might* try to inject your new method directly into the existing `Model` class (or substitute your entire subclass back into the module) so you won't need to change any code that uses `Model`. But that has its own peril. Certainly what you have is good enough that you could do some tests to see whether it actually helps.

Comment: Hmm, I think there are two possible questions here: "Does it make sense to use memcache to cache database entities by key" (which you have answered in terms of how to decide that for a particular application and entity kind), and "Does it make sense to do it this way" (which you haven't addressed).

Answer (score 1):

The idea of caching is fine (though as others have shown you have to be careful with invalidation). However I would not override get_by_name() to do it. I would write separate functions to handle the caching, so the readers of your code can clearly see that you are not using the standard get_by_name(). Also note that get_by_name() is a really thin layer on top of get() with a Key object -- you should probably offer that API as well.

Answer (score 0):

I used memcache to cache the entities too, and I think it is a good idea to speed up the db operations.
I choose to add a get_key method to class model because the memcache/datastore proxy can be reused in many classes.

**Define a general memcache db proxy**

```
#mydb.py
def get_cache(keys):
    """ not support async operation
    because Async operation conflict with cache logiclly 
    """
    if not isinstance(keys, list) and not isinstance(keys, tuple):
        keys = [keys]

    keys = [str(k) for k in keys]
    results = memcache.get_multi(keys) #@UndefinedVariable
    keys_not_in_cache = [k for k in keys if k not in results] 

    if keys_not_in_cache:
        values = db.get([db.Key(k) for k in keys_not_in_cache])
        results_from_db = dict(zip(keys_not_in_cache, values))
        results.update(results_from_db)
        memcache.set_multi(results_from_db) #@UndefinedVariable

    return [results[k] for k in keys]        

def put_cache(values):
    """ Not support async operation
    """
    if not isinstance(values, list):
        values = [values]

    db.put(values)

    keys_str = [(str(k.key()), k) for k in values]
    memcache.set_multi(dict(keys_str)) #@UndefinedVariable    

def delete_cache(values):
    """ Not Support Async Operation
    """
    if not isinstance(values, list):
        values = [values]

    db.delete(values)

    keys_str = [str(k.key()) for k in values]
    memcache.delete_multi(keys_str) #@UndefinedVariable
```

**Usage Example**

```
# for the class want to use this feature
class User(db.Model):
    email = db.EmailProperty()

    @classmethod
    def get_key(cls, email):
        return db.Key.from_path(cls.__name__, email)

# Using memcache db proxy
user_keys = [User.get_key(USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS) for USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS in ALL_USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS]
users = mydb.get_cache(user_keys)
```